# Jquery stack overflow in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, overflow

I got "Stack overflow at line: 2" in IE8. Line of error is:

```
return typeof f!="undefined"&&(!a||f.event.triggered!==a.type)?f.event.dispatch.apply(i.elem,arguments):b
```

in jQuery. Any Idea?! Here is the page:

http://www.compexlogistics.net/services

Try switching between "Intra UAE" and "International" in second page. Also it wont render background of items too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my-self

It was a recursive call. I don't know why it was recursive in IE but any way.